# Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have _plugins/lunrjs/jekyll_lunr_js_search.rb or one of its dependencies installed

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

**When compiling Jekyll project with plugin [jekyll_lunr_js_search](https://github.com/slashdotdash/jekyll-lunr-js-search) always getting following error in windows. However it compiles on gitlabci.**

Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have D:/myproject/_plugins/lunrjs/jekyll_lunr_js_search.rb or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- v8' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!

**Upon using `gem install jekyll-lunr-js-search` following error:**

```
C:\MyProj>gem install jekyll-lunr-js-search
Fetching: json-2.0.3.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-2.0.3
Fetching: ref-2.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed ref-2.0.0
Fetching: libv8-3.16.14.19.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll-lunr-js-search:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8
C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170310-14120-1y669dw.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/builder.rb:86:in `setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, but it is currently 3.4.4 (RuntimeError)
        from C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/builder.rb:53:in `build_libv8!'
        from C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
        from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/libv8-3.16.14.19/gem_make.out
```

** FILE CONTENTS (gem_make.out)**

```
current directory: C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8
C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170310-14120-1y669dw.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/builder.rb:86:in `setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, but it is currently 3.4.4 (RuntimeError)
    from C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/builder.rb:53:in `build_libv8!'
    from C:/APPs/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

**NOTE:**
I've both python v2 and v3 installed and working fine. Tested python shell using `py -2` output follows:

```
C:\>py -2
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Placed "jekyll_lunr_js_search.rb" inside _plugins folder

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the `lib` directory, you'll see that the ruby file is `jekyll-lunr-js-search.rb` instead of `jekyll_lunr_js_search.rb`. Moreover, it is also available as a Rubygem package.

Simply add the gem to the `:jekyll_plugins` group in your `Gemfile`, run `bundle install` and proceed building / serving with Jekyll.

Comment: I renamed `jekyll-lunr-js-search.rb` file which had no effect on plugin functioning as already tried rename back. Rubygem method also won't work. Error is same

Comment: Were you able to successfully install the plugin via `bundle install` or `gem install jekyll-lunr-js-search`?

Comment: No this failed, I've placed output in **EDITED** question

Comment: Windows support for `libv8` will probably have to wait till the [Rubyinstaller2](https://github.com/larskanis/rubyinstaller2) project ships a compatible DevKit to compile the libv8 extension

Comment: This answer helped me resolve a different dependency issue I was struggling with -- make sure your .rb file is the same as your package name folks!